# PHP: getimagesize returns imagetype constant's value instead of IMAGETYPE_XXX constant

Tags: php, getimagesize

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) for getimagesize function:

> Index 2 is one of the IMAGETYPE_XXX constants indicating the type of
>   the image.

However when I use getimagesize I get the values of the constants instead. For example this is for a gif:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1246
    [1] => 1397
    [2] => 1
    [3] => width="1246" height="1397"
    [bits] => 6
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/gif
)
```

And this is for a png:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 900
    [1] => 900
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="900" height="900"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

I expect to get IMAGETYPE_GIF or IMAGETYPE_PNG instead of 1 and 3.

I can deal with this in my application but I wonder why I get the values instead of the constants.

My PHP version is 5.6.14. Just in case it is related, GD and exif extensions are both installed and enabled. I just call

```
getimagesize($pathToImage)
```

without second parameter.

Comment: So what is the value of those `IMAGETYPE_X` constants? They are mere placeholders to avoid so-called "magic numbers" in code.

Comment: Constant is a **value**. And value of constant `IMAGETYPE_GIF` is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constant consists of nothing but its value. It effectively **is** the value, just by another name.

```
IMAGETYPE_GIF === 1 // true
```

That's basically the same as saying you didn't expect

```
echo 0xff;
```

to print `255`, but `0xff`.
`0xff` **is** `255`.

Those are just different human-readable representations for the same value.